# Can the initial setup of XIB elements done anywhere else except viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, viewdidload

In my application, I have a `TabBarController` (which has 3 `ViewControllers` as `tabBarItems`) that is presented from another `ViewController` (Called `HomeViewController`). The `HomeViewController` has three buttons, which on being pressed shows the respective controller in the tabBarController.

The Controller in the second `tabBarItem` processes some info and sends that info to the controller in the first tabBarItem, which that updates its table and shows the processed data. However, the problem is  the  `ViewDidLoad` method of first controller.

In it's `viewDidLoad` method, i am hiding the table initially, so that if the user clicks the first button on the `HomeViewController`, the empty table isn't visible to him. This goes according to plan in case if the user clicks the first button on `HomeViewController` (to present the first view controller)

The issue is: if the user first goes to the second `viewController` from the `HomeViewController`, then the `viewDidLoad` method of it is called (which is not an issue). However, when the user goes to the first Viewcontroller from the second `ViewController`, the `viewDidLoad` method of the first `Viewcontroller` is called, and my table is hidden..!! which needs to be actually shown.

I know my problem is hard to understand this way, but can anyone please help??

here's the code of my first `ViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"View Did Load of CCVC");

    //self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar.png"]];

    [self.customercareSearchbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dark_grey_search_back.png"]];

    [self.view addSubview:self.customercareSearchbar];
    [self.view addSubview:self.customerCareTableView];

    self.customercareSearchbar.delegate = self;
    self.customerCareTableView.delegate = self;

    //[self.customerCareTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.customerCareTableView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];

     ////HERE LIES THE Main PROBLEM

    [self.customerCareTableView setHidden:YES];
    [self.customercareSearchbar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

IS it possible to move

```
[self.customerCareTableView setHidden:YES];
    [self.customercareSearchbar becomeFirstResponder];
```

in any other method?? i know it won't work in `init` because the views are loaded after `init` is called..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some logic based on values you receive from second ViewController, in `ViewWillAppear` of your First ViewController, so as to set your customerCareTableView hidden property to NO.

Comment: was a little more complicated than that.. had to set two flags in the first controller.. One confirmed that the control has been passed from the second controller, and other confirmed if the view has been presented before.. But my job done.. thanks for the hint..